# How to add new entry in context menu in Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, context-menu, nautilus, metacity

There is a very useful entry in gnome's context menu when clicking on any file:
*Open with gedit* (the first entry in the context menu).

I'd like to add similar one, for my second favourite editor.

The question is how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the "nautilus-actions" package

Then, In the following location :

System -> Preferences -> Nautilus Actions Configuration

Click on "Add"

```
In Menu Item & Action:
Label: Open with ..
Path: <Path to executable>
Parameters:

In Conditions:
Filenames: <Give a filter>
Match Case: [selected]
Mimetypes: <Give the mime type>
```

Comment: i don't see this menu item ("Nautilus Actions Configuration") on Ubuntu 10.04.  can you add what command it runs or what version of Ubuntu you have that provides this menu item?

Comment: Could you try installing the nautilus-actions package and then try the above. I have this working on 10.04, with the said package installed.

Comment: @quack quixote ♦ Thanks. Any chance to make the new context menu entry appear as first?